# Python, pdfminer, cropbox HOW?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, crop, pdfminer

How do I use PDFminer in python to crop a page using crop box and save the cropped page in a new pdf? Documentation is non-existent and the internet has no answers.

Comment: I would think a standalone tool like `cpdf` or `pdftk` would be a better choice for this, although the `cpdf` documentation is quite opaque as well.

Comment: @TimRoberts I get the coordinates of the things o want to crop with pdfminer, would those coordinates be the same of the ones mentioned in  the libraries you mentioned?

Comment: Experimentation will be required.  "Coordinates" in a PDF file are an ill-defined concept.  Usually, you'll use points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, crop box did not actually crop the pdf so if you are trying to use it to crop, you cant.